# BLE device with Apple's HAP

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, homekit, ios-homekit

I have a Raspberry Pi that acts as a BLE peripheral. I want to add Apple's HomeKit Accessory Protocol (HAP) to the Raspberry Pi's BLE code, to control the BLE device using Homekit. I would like to avoid implementing HAP over the internet.

The closest resource I found is https://gist.github.com/KhaosT/6ff09ba71d306d4c1079. However, this gist makes it seem like there are many unknowns with that process.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, any info or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have MFi subscription?

Comment: I do not. Do I need one? This is just a personal project, so it seems like an unnecessary step to me.

Comment: The whole specification for peripherals are restricted only to those with MFi subscription.

Comment: So my only options are to either sign up for MFi, or to connect the Raspberry Pi to Homekit using https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge (which is over the internet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned at https://developer.apple.com/homekit/ under Accessory Developers, you need to first sign up for MFi and then you will get access to all the resources you need in order to implement homekit. All source code you can find publicly online is against Apple's license since they prohibit public redistribution of documentation and source code of implementations.